# Recommender System using SciKit-Learn's cross_validate, missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having an issue where I am trying to create a recommender system for a local newspaper (as a school project), but I am running into trouble when I am trying to use the cross_validate function from the model_selection library.

I am trying to use SVD and obtain the f1 score. But I am a bit confused. So this is unsupervised learning, and I do not have a test set, so I want to use KFolding for the cross validation. I believe the number of folds for this is denoted by the "cv" parameter in the cross_validate function. Is this correct?

The problem arise when I try to run the code, as I get the following stack trace: https://hastebin.com/kidoqaquci.tex

I am not passing anything to the "y" parameter of the cross_validate function, but is this wrong? Is not this where the test set should go? And as I said, I do not have any test set as this is unsupervised. I have looked at the example in chapter 3.1.1.1 here:  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

And it looks like they are passing in a "target" for the dataset in the cross_validate function. But why are they passing both a target set AND the cv parameter? Does not a cv value above 1 indicate that kfolding should be used and that the fold left out is to be used as the target (test) set?

Or am I completely misunderstanding something? Why am I getting the "missing argument" error in the stack trace?

This is the code that is failing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score as cv
from sklearn.decomposition.truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD
import pandas as pd

# keywords_data_filename = 'keywords_data.txt'
active_data_filename = 'active_time_data.txt'

header = ['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating']
# keywords_data = pd.read_csv(keywords_data_filename, sep='*', names=header, engine='python')
active_time_data = pd.read_csv(active_data_filename, sep='*', names=header, engine='python')


# Number of users in current set
print('Number of unique users in current data-set', active_time_data.user_id.unique().shape[0])
print('Number of unique articles in current data-set', active_time_data.item_id.unique().shape[0])

# SVD allows us to look at our input matrix as a product of three smaller matrices; U, Z and V.
# In short this will help us discover concepts from the original input matrix,
# (subsets of users that like subsets of items)
# Note that use of SVD is not strictly restricted to user-item matrices
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5mlg91as1c

algorithm = TruncatedSVD()

# Finally we run our cross validation in n folds, where n is denoted by the cv parameter.
# Verbose can be adjusted by an integer to determine level of verbosity.
# We pass in our SVD algorithm as the estimator used to fit the data.
# X is our data set that we want to fit.
# Since our estimator (The SVD algorithm), We must either define our own estimator, or we can simply define how it
# score the fitting.
# Since we currently evaluate the enjoyment of our users per article highly binary, (Please see the rate_article fn in
# the filter script), we can easily decide our precision and recall based on whether or not our prediction exactly
# matches the binary rating field in the test set.
# This, the F1 scoring metric seems an intuitive choice for measuring our success, as it provides a balanced score
# based on the two.

cv(estimator=algorithm, X=active_time_data, scoring='f1', cv=5, verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

1) TruncatedSVD is a [dimensionality reduction algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#lsa). So I am not understanding how do you intend to calculate the f1_score.

2) [f1_score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) is traditionally used on classification tasks, and have a formula:

```
f1 = 2*recall*precision
    --------------------
     recall + precision
```

where recall and precision are defined in terms of True Positives, True Negative, False Positive, False Negative which in turn need the true classes and predicted classes to be calculated.

3) cv = 1 makes no sense. In `cross_val_score`, cv denotes the number of folds. So cv = 5 denotes that in each fold, 80% data will be in training and 20% in testing. So how do you intend to test the data without the true labels of ground truth of some sort.